# How to assign a particular value to each cell of a datagrview from a sql server table

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a college project which provides an entire week's course schedule to students. The thing is the entire schedule for a 10 week course is already present in the Sql server database table(named it 'master table')

The table has columns: `Week_number, date, time, mon_firsthalf, mon_secondhalf, tue_firsthalf`...and so on upto saturday..for  10 weeks. The thing is I want the students to see only the current week's schedule and the table should just have columns: `day_of_the_week,time,1st_half,2nd_half`.

Is it possible to pull the current week's data(just a row) from the master table and re-arrange it in the second one which should be displayed on a datagridview in winforms(using c# ). I am a beginner and can't seem get through.

Comment: How are you pulling the data now?  If you use a SQL statement you could add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @ D Stanley I was actually displaying the entire master table as it is.. but the project moderator wants me to just display  the current week's data on the datagridview in a daily format mentioned above.

Comment: ...so use a SQL WHERE clause

Comment: In the master table the entire week's schedule is in a single row and in the datagridview, each day's schedule has to be in a seperate row..so my problem is how do I pull and re-arrange the data?